# listings without page-break

Tags: listings

I'm newbie of Latex, and trying to use listings.

My package is following,

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption,multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{inconsolata}



\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{pblue}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{pgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{pred}{rgb}{0.9,0,0}
\definecolor{pgrey}{rgb}{0.46,0.45,0.48}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.6}
\definecolor{cyan}{rgb}{0.0,0.6,0.6}


\usepackage[newfloat]{minted}
\usepackage{listings}

 \lstset{language=Java,
  showspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  breaklines=true,
  showstringspaces=false,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  commentstyle=\color{pgreen},
  keywordstyle=\color{pblue},
  stringstyle=\color{pred},
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  moredelim=[il][\textcolor{pgrey}]{$$},
  moredelim=[is][\textcolor{pgrey}]{\%\%}{\%\%}
}

\lstset{
 language=XML,
 basicstyle=\ttfamily,
 columns=fullflexible,
 showstringspaces=false,
 commentstyle=\color{gray}\upshape
 }

\lstdefinelanguage{XML}
{
morestring=[b]",
morestring=[s]{>}{<},
morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
stringstyle=\color{black},
identifierstyle=\color{darkblue},
keywordstyle=\color{cyan},
morekeywords={xmlns,version,type}% list your attributes here
}
```

And, my XML code is

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=XML]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- when there are too many cars -->
    <policy id="1" priority="10">
    </policy>
\end{lstlisting}
\caption{Example code policy}
\label{lst:policyex}
\end{figure}
```

To add this to listoffigures, I surrounded it with figure tag.

The problem is, my code of XML is alone in one page.

I want to wrap my XML code with paragraphs, instead of page break.

I tried using minipage, float and it does not work either.

What should I do??

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please delete the "answer" and integrate the code into your posting. Moreover, extend the code to a MWE (minimal working example), starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, such that we can copy and paste the code to analyze the problem. Use the [edit button](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/335787/edit) left below your original posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{lstlisting}[language=XML]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- when there are too many cars -->
    <policy id="1" priority="10">
    </policy>
\end{lstlisting}
\caption{Example code policy}
\label{lst:policyex}
\end{figure}
```

I just added `htb` option into figure tag and `\centering`..